# Fail to remove ef entity with parent property required

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am not fantastic with EF so maybe it's an easy one.

I Have

```
    public void DeleteLicense(int licenseId)
    {
        var entityToDelete = context.Licenses.Find(licenseId);
        context.Licenses.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }
```

I have checked that it finds correct license, and context is a ninject (one per request) DbContext,

But I get a weird error when I call SaveChanges() on the context after running the function above. I get: "**The CustomerName field is required.**"

Now this is weird because CustomerName is in Account (not Licence) they are linked, but still. So here follows some more:

My Account entity

```
[Required]
public String CustomerName { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
...
```

My License entity

```
public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
...
```

My fluent setup

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasMany(x => x.Licenses)
.WithRequired(x => x.Account).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I don't understand, because even if there is a failing restraint then why missing CustomerName. I don't touch CustomerName when I delete a license and the CustomerName is set since before.

**Update**

So here is some more details from the code. The full execution path as far as I can see is

**DeleteLicenseAPI** below takes the call, the ID is correct, it passes over to a private function.
The private function calls the **DeleteLicense** shown close to the top of the question.
The **Commit()** only calls **context.SaveChanges();**

```
public ActionResult DeleteLicenseAPI(int licenseId)
{
        if (DeleteLicense(licenseId))
        {
            return Content("ok");
        }

        return Content("[[[Failed to delete license]]]");

}

private bool DeleteLicense(int licenseId)
{
        //todo: sort out busniess rules for delete, is cascaded?
        _accountRepository.DeleteLicense(licenseId);
        _accountRepository.Commit();

        return true;
}
```

The **_accountRepository** looks like this

```
public class EFAccountRepository : EntityFrameworkRepository<Account>
, IAccountRepository

public EFAccountRepository(EvercateContext context) : base(context)
{       
}
```

And here is the code in Ninject that sets it all up

```
kernel.Bind<EvercateContext>()
.To<EvercateContext>()
.InRequestScope()
.WithConstructorArgument("connectionStringOrName", "EvercateConnection");


kernel.Bind<IAccountRepository>().To<EFAccountRepository>();
```

So even tho I use Unit of Work as far as I can see (and it shouldn't) nothing else is called in this request before running SaveChanges.
Is there any way to see what a DbContext will do on SaveChanges, without actually running the method (as it throws **DbEntityValidationException**)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make sense. Is this `DeleteLicense` method part of a bigger unit of work in which you maybe inadvertently create an `Account`?

Comment: Good to know that it's not just me. I updated with more details in the question. But the summary is: Can I see what SaveChanges will do without running it?

Comment: You can override `SaveChanges` in your `DbContext` and check the content of `this.ChangeTracker.Entries()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine that this weird exception could occur if you are initializing the `Account` navigation property in the `License` constructor like so:

```
public License
{
    Account = new Account();
}
```

The flow when you call...

```
var entityToDelete = context.Licenses.Find(licenseId);
context.Licenses.Remove(entityToDelete);
```

...is then probably:

- `License` entity gets loaded (without navigation property `Account`) and attached to the context (state `Unchanged`)
- The constructor sets the `Account` navigation property, but it doesn't get attached (state `Detached`)
- When you call `Remove` for the `License` entity `DetectChanges` is called internally by EF. It detects that `License.Account` is refering to a detached entity and attaches it to the context (in state `Added`). The state of the `License` is changed to `Deleted`.
- When you call `SaveChanges` the change tracker finds two entities: The `License` in state `Deleted` and the `Account` in state `Added`.
- Validation runs and finds that the required property `CustomerName` for the entity `Account` that is supposed to be inserted into the database is `null` (because only the default constructor of `Account` is called).
- The validation exception is thrown.

I'm not sure if the details are right but something like that is probably happening.

In any case you should delete the `Account = new Account();` from the `License` constructor and also check if you initialize other *reference* navigation properties in entity constructors in your codebase as well. (Initializing empty navigation *collections* is OK.) This is a common source of notoriously strange problems that are difficult to find and understand.

Comment: We learn something new every day. Thank you very much for your excellent answer!

Comment: Slauma, can I borrow your crystal ball for a few days? :)

Comment: @GertArnold: With his own answer that basically said that `entityToDelete.Account` was found in the change tracker it was possible to guess without crystal ball :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried overriding SaveChanges as recommended.
When I did I found a License about to be deleted (as it should) but I also found an Account about to be created.

I changed the DeleteLicense as displayed below.

```
    public void DeleteLicense(int licenseId)
    {
        var entityToDelete = context.Licenses.Find(licenseId);
        entityToDelete.Account = null;
        context.Licenses.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }
```

And right away the code works. The License is removed and the account is still there, but no new account is created.

But why, I do not understand why at all.
Is it something in the relation i set with fluent api?

Comment: Reading this I'd suspect that you have a `Account = new Account();` in your `License` entity constructor. This `Account` probably gets added to the context (in state `Added`) when you call `...Remove(...)` due to the automatic change detection that happens inside of `Remove`. Because that `Account` is only created with a default constructor `CustomerName` is probably `null` which is causing the validation exception. Remove that line in the constructor (assuming it really exists).

Comment: Brilliant!! That's it! If you put it as an Answer I can accept it for the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because my entity had a `[Required]` property that was of type `int?` which made it nullable. While inspecting the model that came back from the db I saw the property had a value but the entity that ended up being saved to the database had that value stripped during `SaveChanges` for some reason. When I switched the value to the expected `int` type all worked just fine. :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and for me, it looked like I hadn't correctly established the relationship between Parent and Child in their respective classes.

My fix was to add the attributes specified below to the Child class, for the property that represented its Parent's Id

```
public class Child
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Parent"), Column(Order = 2)]  // adding this line fixed things for me
    public string ParentId {get; set;}
}

public class Parent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children{ get; set; }
}
```